# Scipy griddata interpolation results in lots on NaNs

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate a sparse matrix to fill the 0 values. I'm using numpy `griddata` function starting from the example available [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html). Just as a reference, the data I'm starting from has the shape of a 1 channel image and looks like this (roughly 1 data point every 4x4):
[image: sparse data]

The code that should do the interpolation is this:

```
# a contains the data
grid_y, grid_x = np.mgrid[0:128:1, 0:384:1]
points = []
for z in zip(a.nonzero()[0],a.nonzero()[1]):
    points.append(np.array(z))

values = [a[x] for x in zip(a.nonzero()[0],a.nonzero()[1])]

interp = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
```

But for some reason, this is the result of the interpolation:
[image: results]
Where the white parts in the image are actually NaNs. From my understanding of the example, I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only interpolating to the extent of the x-axis, because `grid_x` and `grid_y` are swapped in order in the last line of your example. Just reverse, like so

```
interp = griddata(points, values, (grid_y, grid_x), method='cubic')
```

Comment: After seeing your explanation, it looks clear from the image I posted! Thanks